# Does Ubuntu support passkeys, like Apple, Google and Microsoft do?

Tags: security, authentication

[Passkeys](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2022/10/passkeys-microsoft-apple-and-googles-password-killer-are-finally-here/) are a new feature that is being supported more and more. The FIDO alliance released [a standard for passkeys](https://fidoalliance.org/passkeys/). Apple announced support for passkeys on iOS 16 and macOS with Safari 16.1, Google say they will support it in Chrome, and Microsoft will support it in Edge and Windows Hello. PayPal recently [rolled out support](https://newsroom.paypal-corp.com/2022-10-24-PayPal-Introduces-More-Secure-Payments-with-Passkeys) on their websites.

Here's a website that demonstrates passkey functionality: https://www.passkeys.io/

My question is: does Ubuntu support passkeys? Do browsers on Ubuntu (like Firefox or Chromium) support passkeys?

Comment: Eventually someone can tell you more information. Maybe there is some discussion between developers ...

Comment: The best you can do up to now is 2FA TOTP or HOTP: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/draft-two-factor-authentication-with-totp-hotp/31630

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use passkeys on Ubuntu with these **browsers**:

- Google Chrome
- Microsoft Edge (there's a version available for Linux)
- Mozilla Firefox, with [this clarification](https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/ideas/support-webauthn-passkeys/idc-p/50453/highlight/true#M29301):

  > - Web Platform support of Passkeys is available on [...] Linux, (though there is not platform passkey provider on Linux. We support Passkeys stored on USB security keys on Linux).
  > - Sign-in with nearby Device is [not] available on [...] Linux, though Chrome does not support nearby on Linux either.

Some password manager extensions (like [Bitwarden](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/bitwarden-password-manager/)) support passkeys on Firefox.

These **security capabilities** are supported:

- Security keys like Yubikey (but only certain versions, my old Yubikey did not work)
  [image: Photo of Yubikey devices]
- Not supported: <s>face recognition</s>
- Not supported: <s>fingerprint recognition</s>

Try it out at this website: https://www.passkeys.io/

If you have an updated Android smartphone or iPhone, try it out there as well using the same website. The experience is noticeably better there.

Comment: That leaves the question whether or not there is support for passkeys *on OS level*, like in Windows or Android, which is half of this question

Comment: Oct 2023: passkeys cannot be created in latest Chrome (nor FF) on Linux.

Comment: oct 2023 - ubuntu 22.04 - I have passkey working on chrome with my pixel 5. Doesn't appear to work from the CLI.

Comment: Bitwarden supports passkeys

Comment: https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/ideas/support-webauthn-passkeys/idc-p/50453/highlight/true#M29301 says "We support Passkeys stored on USB security keys on Linux" for Firefox 122.

Answer (score 11):

My Experience as of March 2024.

I tested all the methods below on a passkey demo site https://www.passkeys.io/ . This site allows you to create an account with an email address as the userID and a passkey. It also allows you to create additional passkeys using different hardware/software.

## TL;DR

**KeePassXC** seems like the best way to create, store and manage passkeys for Ubuntu, among those I have tried.

## Ubuntu OS level support

My computers do not have fingerprint scanners. Without additional hardware or software neither Chrome nor Firefox gives me the option to generate passkeys on the webpages that support it. As far as I can tell there is no OS level support outside the browsers for passkeys.

<s>The main issue is storage and management of passkeys without an USB-key is not possible in Ubuntu as far as I can tell.</s> The latest [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/) from the PPA can store and use passkeys. See the **Additional Software** section below.

## Additional Hardware

### Google Titan Security Key

This is another alternative to Yubikeys described in the [accepted  answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437604/does-ubuntu-support-passkeys-like-apple-google-and-microsoft-do/1466723#1466723). I use a Google Titan Security Key (USB C one).

[image: Titan Security Keys]

This key can store up to 250 passkeys in it. As far as I know, there is no way to copy, move, delete, or otherwise manually manage the passkeys stored in this USB key.

### Android Phone

**Note:** Android phone as a passkey authentication only works with Chrome, and **not** Firefox. Passkeys created using a phone are stored online in the [Google Password Manager](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6208650?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid). However, just Chrome in Ubuntu without an Android phone can't use this option, as far as I can tell.

I use a Google Pixel phone as a nearby passkey authentication device. But any recent version of Android phone should work.

Some websites allow **passkey authentication using a nearby device**. In this case, the phone. Once the phone is set up for a particular website for passkey authentication, the website sends a message to the phone and authentication is completed with bio-metric authentication like face recognition or fingerprint using the phone's
camera/sensor.

A QR code from the website may need to be scanned using the phone to crate passkey using a phone.

Bluetooth must work on both the phone and the Ubuntu computer for this to work.

Reference: https://www.passkeys.io/#How-to-use-a-passkey

## Additional Software

Instead of using an USB-key like the Google Titan or the Yubikey, or a phone or tablet as additional hardware, You could use a password management software. The only one I have tried is KeePassXC.

### KeePassXC (version 2.7.7 and above)

I installed KeePassXC from the PPA and the browser extensions for Chrome and Firefox. In the Settings page of the KeePassXC-Browser Extension, scroll down in the General Tab till you see the **Passkeys** section. Make sure both

1. Enable Passkeys
2. Enable PassKeys Fallback

boxes are checked.

[image]

I tried this in Firefox and Chrome. The KeePassXC application (and the database) was open in the background and the browser extension was active. I already created the first passkey and took the screenshots during creation of a second passkey under the same account. When I clicked on the **Create a passkey** button on the web, the following popup showed up from the KeePassXC browser:

[image]

Pressing the Cancel button gave me the "Fall back option" of using the USB-Key by showing the Enter PIN popup window:

[image]

By entering the PIN of my USB-key, I could create a new passkey and store it in the Google Titan Security Key.

In chrome I could press **Use a different passkey** button instead of the PIN, and get another popup to store the passkey on my phone:

[image]

This option was not available in Firefox.

See the [official KeePassXC guide for passkey](https://keepassxc.org/docs/KeePassXC_UserGuide#_passkeys) for more details.

## Browser Experiences

I have only tried Chrome and Firefox.

### Chrome

I found that it is easier to create new passkeys in Chrome as compared with Firefox. In some sites Firefox won't give me the option to create a passkey, while it would in Chrome.

The creation of a passkey on the USB-key involves entering the PIN and touching the touch-pad on the USB-key when prompted. Chrome also allows creation of a passkey to be kept online by selecting the phone or nearby authentication device. Finally, I could also create a passkey using KeePassXC as long as I had the password database open in the app and the browser extension installed and configured for passkeys.

Once the passkey is created for a website and is stored in the USB-key, the Google Password Manager, or in KeePassXC, I can login to that site by either:

1. Plugging in the USB-key, entering the PIN, and touching the touch
   pad on the USB-key.
2. Selecting my Phone from list of devices and following the
   instructions on the phone.
3. Clicking on the Authenticate button on the popup from the KeePassXC browser extension.

**Note,** different websites have taken different approaches to using passkeys. Some use it instead of password. Others use it along with the password as a form of second factor in a two factor authentication process.

### Firefox

My experience with Firefox has been flaky. In most sites I can use the passkey in Firefox once it is created using Chrome. One exception I have found is Amazon. I can use the passkey stored in the USB-key or KeePassXc to log into Amazon using Chrome. This option is not offered by Amazon in Firefox.

Firefox does not give me the opportunity to use my phone as the passkey storage and manager.

## A list of sites I have tried:

| Site | Titan Key | Titan Key | Phone | KeepPassXC | KeepPassXC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **Chrome** | **Firefox** | **Chrome** | **Chrome** | **Firefox** |
| Synology | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Amazon | Yes | **No** | Yes | Yes | **No** |
| Dropbox | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Google | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Microsoft | Yes | Yes | Yes | **No** | **No** |
| Yahoo | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Bank of America | **No** | **No** | Yes |  |  |
| CVS | No | **Yes** | No | No | No |
| Caremark | No | No | No | No | No |
| Home Depot | No | No | No | No | No |
| LinkedIn | No | No | No | No | No |

[Screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv4Ir.png)

Passkeys should work in all the sites mentioned in the table (and screenshot) above. However, those towards the bottom of the list did not offer the passkey option when I tried to create one.

Home Depot allowed me to create a passkey using KeePassXC, but I didn't get the option to use the passkey when I tried to login.

## Summary

I have tried three options for Ubuntu to create and store passkeys for passkey enabled websites:

1. Security Key (USB): **Disadvantages:** There is no way to manually manage or export/import the stored passkeys.
2. Nearby Device (Phone): **Disadvantages:** The passkeys are stored online. There is no way to export/import passkeys. Does not work with Firefox.
3. Password Manager (KeePassXC): **Advantage:** Passkeys are stored locally.

Hope this helps

Comment: @muru Thanks for converting the screenshot to a nice markdown table. I didn't know I could do that. Copy and paste from LibreOffice Calc resulted in the picture. This is much better.

Comment: Thank you for all that testing! From Calc, if you can get a CSV, I think `pandoc` might be able to make a Markdown table of it (`pandoc -f csv -t gfm-raw_html`). (Also, please double check if I got the table right - transcribing larger tables is more error-prone)

Comment: Didn't know about KeePassXC! Tell me if am I right: so there is no way to have passkeys in sync from Linux to android, right?

Comment: @nulll If the passkeys are stored in the Android phone locally (I know Pixel does), then you are right. If you allow Chrome in the phone to save passwords and create passkeys on the phone for a website using Chrome, it will be saved online. Then you can use that passkey in Ubuntu and Chrome using the phone as an additional device as described above.

Comment: @nulll See [this Google help page about passkeys in android](https://support.google.com/android/answer/14124480?hl=en). If Android apps like KeePass2Android, or KeePassXD support passkeys in Android in the future, it may be possible to use the same database used in KeePassXC in Ubuntu with the corresponding app in Android for passkey sync and management in Android and Ubuntu.